# PHP - get the biggest possible integer match from an array of integers

Tags: php, math

I have an array of integers:

```
$intArr = [2, 4, 8, 16];
```

Given an $inputInt of 8, I need the biggest integer match from that array, which should return 8 of course.

The following function needs modification:

```
function getBiggestMatch($intputInt) {
    $intArr = [2, 4, 8, 16];

    foreach($intArr as $key => $value) {
        if($key < $intputInt) {
            $biggestMatch = $value;
        }
    }

    return $biggestMatch;
}

$biggestMatch = getBiggestMatch(8); // should return 8, but returns 2 now
```

This function will return 2, because that is the first time that $key < $intInput. The desired result needs to be 8 from $intArr.

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal?

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, a moment. I pressed Enter by accident without having posted any code yet :-)

Comment: I do not understand well. What is your desired result in your example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the `$value`, not the `$key`. This is returning 8.

```
<?php
function getBiggestMatch($intputInt) {
    $intArr = [2, 4, 8, 16];

    foreach($intArr as $key => $value) {
        if($value <= $intputInt) {
            $biggestMatch = $value;
        }
    }

    return $biggestMatch;
}

echo getBiggestMatch(8); // should return 8, but returns 2 now
?>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my array actually consisted out of multiple key => value pairs. So I had to match on the $key, but using the '<=' operators actually did the trick.

Comment: The input will never be 0.

Comment: @Beeelze why would you want a solution that does only work in some cases?

Comment: The condition needs a double check. If you put a lower value at the end the function returns that value.

Comment: @elchininet you could use sort($intArr) for this

Comment: Of course. But if you add a double check the original array will no be modified.

Comment: @Rizier123 How come it doesn't work with input 0 and 15? If input is 0, it returns nothing. If it's 15, it returns 8 (the biggest match <= 15.).

Comment: 0 returns in an undefined notice and 15 returns 8, even tough 16 is clearly nearer to 15.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

First of all, just to make sure, we reindex the array and sort it with [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) and [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

After this we loop through the array with a while loop and always check if the next key exists and the current `key => element` is smaller than the input `$number`:

```
Check if next element exists   Check that current array value is smaller than the input
      ┌─────────┴───────┐    ┌─────────┴────────┐
while(isset($arr[$key+1]) && $arr[$key] < $number)
    $key++;  //→ Go to next key, which must exist
```

Now after the while loop the `$key => value` can point to either a value which is the same as the input or higher. Now we just check the following:

- `value == input` (`$arr[$key] == $number`) => return current value (`return $arr[$key];`)
- distance between current value to input (`$arr[$key] - $number`) is smaller (`<`) than the distance between the last value to the input (`$number - $arr[$key-1]`) => return current value (`return $arr[$key];`)
- else => return last value (`return $arr[$key-1];`)

Code:

```
<?php

    function getNearestMatch($number) {
        $arr = array_values([2, 4, 8, 16, 23]);
        sort($arr);
        $key = 0;

        while(isset($arr[$key+1]) && $arr[$key] < $number)
            $key++;

        if($arr[$key] == $number || !isset($arr[$key-1]) || $arr[$key] - $number < $number - $arr[$key-1]) 
            return $arr[$key]; 
        else
            return $arr[$key-1];

    }

    //To test it we pass some values to the function
    foreach([0, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 22, 23, 24] as $v)
        echo getNearestMatch($v) . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

output:

```
2
2
2
4
8
8
23
23
23
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do double check because if your array does not have an order the last minor value will return:

```
function getBiggestMatch($intputInt) {

    $intArr = [4, 8, 2, 16];

    $maxInt = false;

    foreach($intArr as $key => $value) {

        if($intputInt >= $value && $maxInt < $value) $maxInt = $value;

    }

    return $maxInt;
}

echo getBiggestMatch(12);
```

[ideone code](http://ideone.com/l4aeo2)

**EDIT**

Following the @Rizier123's recommendation, the function needs to find the max **closest** value (I had not understood very well the original question), this could be a possible solution:

```
function getBiggestMatch($intputInt) {

    $intArr = [4, 8, 2, 16];

    $maxInt = false;
    $diference = 0;

    foreach($intArr as $key => $value) {

        if( $diference == 0 || ($diference > 0 && abs($intputInt - $value) < $diference)  ) {

            $maxInt = $value;

            $diference = abs($intputInt - $value);

        }

    }

    return $maxInt;
}

echo getBiggestMatch(15);
```

[ideone code](http://ideone.com/axJOS5)